# Material-UI Drawer not displaying in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, menu, cross-browser, material-ui

I have a simple react application that is using Material-UI components. The application menu drawer doesn't appear in FF 60.4 but works fine in Chrome.

If I change the state of the drawer in the developers toolbox the drawer appears. Its like the menu icon onClick event handler isn't firing: https://codesandbox.io/s/wo29099yvl

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I move your onClick from the `MenuIcon` to the `IconButton`, it works fine in FF.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rl9kv3950q